# Having trouble converting a floating point to its binary representation

Tags: floating-point, mantissa

Below is a tutorial I'm trying to follow.
[image]

When attempting to convert the number back to its binary representation I get it wrong. Could someone tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
-0.21875
```

binary representation:

```
.00111 = 1.11 * 2^-3
```

since..

```
0.5^3 + 0.5^4 + 0.5^5 = 0.21875
```

with an exponent of..

```
-3 + 127 = 124
```

therefore the binary representation should be:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
1 01111100 11100000000000
```

But why do I get the right answer converting 639.6875 the same way?:

Representation of integer value:

```
1001111111
```

Representation of decimal value:

```
1011
```

Combining and normalizing:

```
1001111111.1011 = 1.0011111111011 * 2^9
```

When normalizing, we place the radix directly to the right of the first 1 right?
biasing with 127 to the exponent, 127+9 = 136:

```
10001000
```

binary representation:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmm
0 10001000 10011111111011
```

Answer (score 0):

#### First value

> (paraphrased) I get the wrong answer when converting -0.21875 back to binary. Why?

For a *normalized* floating-point number, the leading '1' is not written into the bit representation. For example, encoding the binary number 1.0001101 would give a mantissa of 0001101(...).

This fact about normalized FP numbers is covered in the presentation slide that you posted - namely it is the part called `(1 + f)` (instead of just `f`).

Therefore, your binary representation of -0.21875 must have the mantissa bits `11000000000000000000000` (padded on the right to 23 bits long).

#### Second value

> But why do I get the right answer converting 639.6875 the same way?

You don't get the right answer. The correct representation of 639.6875 is:

```
s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
0 10001000 00111111110110000000000
```

#### Code check

We can confirm these values conveniently using Java:

```
printFloat(0b1_01111100_11000000000000000000000);  // -0.21875
printFloat(0b0_10001000_00111111110110000000000);  // 639.6875
printFloat(0b0_10001000_10011111111011000000000);  // 831.84375

void printFloat(int bits) { 
    System.out.println(Float.intBitsToFloat(bits));
}
```

#### A correction

I can see the intent of this line:

> ```
> 0.5^3 + 0.5^4 + 0.5^5 = 0.21875
> ```

but it should be written like so:

```
0.5 * 2^-3 + 0.5 * 2^-4 + 0.5 * 2^-5 = 0.21875
```